# What is the relation between the minority charge profile in the base and the collector current (BJT)?

Tags: transistors, bjt, semiconductors, physics

For a BJT in forward active mode, the minority charge concentration at the base-collector junction is zero. If this is the case, how is a non-zero number of electrons able to make it to the collector? Further, I believe the minority profile (in base) cannot decrease to zero only due to recombination. How does it happen? What does it represent?

Had read some answers, but found none to be satisfactory.